# How to make a selector of extended state from a entity feature inside ngrx?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

**Problem:**
This selector `entity.selectAll` will not include the extended state.

### **Question:**

**How do I include my extend state inside selectAll OR how can I create a custom selector for my selected state?**

My UxeGallery Model is:

```
export interface UxeGallery {
  id: string;
  imgSrc: string;
  name: string;
  details?: string;
}
```

Here I have my EntityState and I have added some state to it:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<UxeGallery> {
  selectedItem: string | null;
  hiddenItem: string | null;
  bottombarTemplate: boolean;
  topbarTemplate: boolean;
  topbarTemplateType: string;
  modalTemplate: boolean;
  canvasTemplate: boolean;
  canvasImg: string | null;
}
```

I create the adapter:

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<UxeGallery> = createEntityAdapter<UxeGallery>();
```

Set the init state:

```
export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
  ids: ['0'],
  entities: {
    '0': {
      imgSrc: 'url',
      name: 'dog',
      details: 'some dog',
    }
  },
  selectedItem: null,
  hiddenItem: null,
  topbarTemplateType: TopbarType.WHITE,
  topbarTemplate: false,
  bottombarTemplate: false,
  modalTemplate: false,
  canvasTemplate: false,
  canvasImg: null,
});
```

Create my featureSelector:

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector<any>('uxeGallery');
```

Export adapter selectors:

```
export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal,
} = adapter.getSelectors(getState);
```

From my app component I selectAll from my entity:

```
import * as fromUxeGallery from '../../reducers/uxe-gallery.reducer';
import { UxeGallery } from '../../uxe-gallery.model';


export class UxeGalleryMasterComponent implements OnInit {
  private obs: Observable<UxeGallery[]>;
  private obsExtended: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromUxeGallery.State>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obs = this.store.pipe(select(fromUxeGallery.selectAll));
    this.obs.subscribe(console.log);
    /**
      This will return
      [
        {
          details:"some dog",
          imgSrc:"url",
          name:"dog"
        }
      ]
    */
  }
}
```

**How can I make a selector that will grab the extended state from my Entity model?**

e.g

```
  selectedItem: null,
  hiddenItem: null,
  topbarTemplateType: TopbarType.WHITE,
  topbarTemplate: false,
  bottombarTemplate: false,
  modalTemplate: false,
  canvasTemplate: false,
  canvasImg: null,
```

UPDATE:

I added this:

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector<any>('uxeGallery');
export const selectFeatureExtended = createSelector(getState, (state: State) => {
  return  {
    selectedItem: state.selectedItem,
    hiddenItem: state.hiddenItem,
    bottombarTemplate: state.bottombarTemplate,
    topbarTemplate: state.topbarTemplate,
    topbarTemplateType: state.topbarTemplateType,
    modalTemplate: state.modalTemplate,
    canvasTemplate: state.canvasTemplate,
    canvasImg: state.canvasImg,
  };
});
```

It feels pretty verbose but if theres no other solution it works as intended :(

Comment: so, what should be the type of this.obs? To get a picture of what you want to get

Comment: Should be the entity type of Uxegallery

Comment: so `Observable<UxeGallery>`? If not please rephrase your question and add a minimal input/output example for the selector. Im having troubles to understand what you want.

Comment: How do I select hiddenItem: string | null; bottombarTemplate: boolean; topbarTemplate: boolean; topbarTemplateType: string; modalTemplate: boolean; canvasTemplate: boolean; canvasImg: string | null

Comment: Please add the explicit type of `this.obs`. Your question is really unclear and without further details in the comments, at least for me, hard to understand.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Ok man I updated the question the best I can does it make Any sense now?